# How do you declare a LinkedList with objects that implement a specific interface?

Tags: java, list, generics, linked-list

Normally one would declare a LinkedList like this: `LinkedList<object> list`. However, I need those objects that also implement a particular interface.

Is there a way to set this in the declaration?

Comment: Just replace object with the interface name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your interface instead of Object

```
LinkedList<MyInterface> list
```

with that you can add whichever class implements MyInterface